# Speed up JOIN with ON specified by BETWEEN two values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am surprised that joining two tables with `ON` specified by `BETWEEN` clause takes so long. In table A the `A.Key` is `UNIQUE`, sorted `ascending`. In table B we have `B.KeyStart` and `B.KeyEnd` columns also sorted ascending, they form exclusive intervals like `1-4, 5-6, 7-11` and so on.

```
SELECT A.Key, B.Column 
FROM tableA as A 
INNER JOIN  tableB as B
ON A.Key BETWEEN B.KeyStart AND B.KeyEnd
```

What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Are the columns indexed? You say that the tables are (pre-)sorted but this  is only possible if the key columns you mention are the clustered indexes: otherwise there is no guarantee how you get the rows delivered in the absence of an order by clause.

Comment: What do you mean by the columns being sorted? Tables do not normally have a particular order, only indexes. Perhaps you could post the CREATE TABLE statements, including all indexes. Also, the execution plan (Query -> Show Execution Plan in Management Studio).

Comment: How many rows do you have in both tables?

Comment: @oryol in table A I got 3 million and in table B 300k. However I use WHERE to trim it by date to 50k, also with a BETWEEN date1 and date2

Comment: Take a look at the actual execution plan to see if the query engine is doing what you think it is. Also, try to update stats, and defrag indexes if that hasn't been done in a while.

Comment: @davek a clustered index does not mean that a select statement will return rows in the order of the clustered index. For queries against small tables with only 1 table involved that is usually the case. If you want the rows ordered in a select statement there is 1 and only 1 way to do it, add an order by. Check out this article which does a nice job of explaining this common myth. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Comment: @Sean: I'm aware of that: I meant that in the absence of a clustered index that will *never* be the case (that rows are returned sorted without an ORDER BY), not that it will *always* be the case if one does exist.

Comment: OK. Your response did not sound like that to me and it is always better to respond and be sure.

Comment: @Sean: I agree! And thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea you can try. As you know to only have *one* match in B for each A, because you know the ranges not to be overlapping, why look at KeyEnd at all? It is always the maximum KeyStart B record for an A record where B.KeyStart is not greater than A.Key.

So we get A, look for the best matching StartKey in B and then access the whole corresponding B record in order to read B.Column. You can use SQL Server's CROSS APPLY here.

```
select a.Key, b.Column
from tableA a
cross apply
( 
  select max(KeyStart) as KeyStart from tableB where tableB.KeyStart <= a.Key
) best
join tableB b on b.KeyStart = best.KeyStart;
```

This may be faster. This may be slower. Just try.

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58e44/3.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly slower then you expect, because you expect the DBMS to know things it doesn't know.

The DBMS doesn't know that there are no overlapping ranges. So from the DBMS's perspective it could even be that all B records range from min Key to max Key, which would mean to join all A records with all B records. Only you know that there will one be only one B record per A record.

So the DBMS must read through all B in order to find out what matches and what does not. As there is no WHERE clause, all records are relevant, so using indexes is rather out of question.

You can help the DBMS by telling it all you know via constraints it understands: KeyStart is unique. KeyEnd is unique. (You cannot tell it there are no overlapping ranges, though.) Maybe it helps, but I actually doubt this.

Furthermore you can create an index containing all values in question, so reading the table itself becomes unnecessary; the index would be read instead. `Index on tableB(KeyStart, KeyEnd, Column)`.

Comment: There is a column in table B with an icon of a key, which is unique. How may I take advantage of that? I have read-only access to db.

Comment: A column containing an item of a key? Do you mean binary image data? I don't think this helps you here. It doesn't even have to do with your query, it seems. So, no, you cannot take any Advantage of this. With only read access to your DB there is almost nothing you can do, because your query is already well-written and straight-forward.

Comment: but I am pretty sure the keys are already defined by the owner. I simply do not know how to write a query to point to the keys. Suppose I used 'Index on tableB(KeyStart, KeyEnd, Column)' what now, how do I call that index in a query?

Comment: You don't. The DBMS uses indexes when it considers their use appropriate. If there were such an index, the DBMS might decide to use it, but it may also decide otherwise. Indexes are not always the faster option.